# Jquery and Ajax Call not working proprly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am trying to display the tabs and trying to fetch data for the tabs , with my below   code I managed to display tabs but my GetManufacturerProductsForCountry action is not been called in my controller. Please correct me if my code is worng.

" %>

```
<%@ Import Namespace="EmsAdmin.Models" %>
```

```
    <% foreach (var country in ((Country[])ViewData["countries"]))
       { %>
    <li><a href="#">
        <%: country.Name %></a> </li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
<div class="panes">

    <% foreach (var country in ((Country[])ViewData["countries"]))
       { %>
    <div class="pane">
        <div style="clear: both;">
            &nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div id="ProductCountry<%:country.Id %>">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var taskInput = "";
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Manufacturers/GetManufacturerProductsForCountry/"+<%:Model.Id %>+<%:country.Id %>,
                type: 'get',
              success: function (data) {
                    taskInput = data;
                    $("#ProductCountry").html(data);

                }
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest calling ajax once on page-load them inserting the html for each one. Too many ajax calls may not work, I believe there is a limit there.

if this did work, your id in ">
does not match $("#ProductCountry").html(data);

Also, for security you can't do an ajax GET by default in MVC, rather decorate your Controller Method with [HttpPost] and specify that in the ajax call.

Answer (score -1):

looks like that id is wrong in jQuery object.

Try with

```
       $("[id*=" + "ProductCountry" + "]").html(data);
```

Instead of

```
         $("#ProductCountry").html(data);
```